# How to place pagination in WordPress? I am trying similar code but it doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to paginate archived post in WordPress when I click "next button" but it doesn't work. Please guide me to do it in a simple way. My code is given below:

```
<div class="grid-wrapper ">
                    <?php  $args = array(
                           'posts_per_page' => 3,
                           'paged' => $paged
                            );
                            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                            ?>

                        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="inner-blog">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2">
                            <div class="post-thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9">
                            <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                       <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                        <li><?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Next Page', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?> »</li>
                        <li><?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Previous Page' ); ?></li>
                    </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
```